# check for strings that are at least 1 character long

Tags: php, string, strlen

I often see [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) used. Are these 2 tests equivalent for all values of `$str`?

`is_string($str) && 0 !== strlen($str)`

`is_string($str) && '' !== $str`

Comment: `is_string($str) && '' !== $str` is redundant since you are testing with !== that already test thath $str has the same type as ''.

Comment: @macjohn it's not redundant because `strlen(false)` and `strlen(null)` both evaluate to 0. It ensures that `$str` is in fact a string.

Comment: @ryanve @macjohn is saying that the `is_string($str)` part of the _second_ test is redundant.

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL It's not redundant in either case. Consider that `$str` may be a non-string type like an array or boolean.

Comment: in the first case, if $str is not a string, and you don't test if $str is a string, strlen will throw an error, since it expects a string as a parameter. In the second case the !== operator test both the type and the content.

Comment: @macjohn What would be the sense in doing it in a way that might throw an error? That's wrong anyway. Try `echo strlen(array());`. It's 5 b/c it casts the array to 'Array'.

Comment: Think that conceptually when you do a test with $a !== $b you are doing a double test: gettype($a) !== gettype($b) && $a != $b. In your example gettype('') !== 'string' && '' != $str

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, those two statements are logically equivalent. My preferred ways to skin this cat:

```
is_string($str) && !empty($str)
```

...though `empty('0')` is `true` (*sigh*, PHP...), so this is probably even better:

```
$str !== ''
```

See also: [Checking if the string is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718986/checking-if-the-string-is-empty) and [Is there a difference between $str == '' and strlen($str) == 0 in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381947/is-there-a-difference-between-str-and-strlenstr-0-in-php)

Comment: `!empty()` AFTER `is_string()` is not optimal.  `!empty()` is ideal when two checks are required -- checking if the variable is declared AND is not falsey.

Answer (score 1):

They're pretty close, except that `strlen()` will return `0` for `NULL` strings, so if your `$str` was `NULL`, the `0 !== strlen($str)` expression in your first test would evaluate to `true`, while the `'' !== $str` in your second test would evaluate to `false`.

Comment: ... but that's largely irrelevant since `is_string(null)` returns `false`, so both expressions would return `false` anyways.

Comment: @NullUserException: Precisely, just an observation :)

Comment: The "bigger" issue with `empty` is that `empty('0')` is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

yes, they are the same..

I would use:

```
is_string($str) && strlen($str) > 0
```

Comment: Thx - If they're the same then why use the one that requires an extra function call? I thought maybe it was faster to use `strlen` but I tested it performance-wise and they were so close that it was hard to tell which was faster.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
strlen($str) > 0
```

!== is a strong type and might not be match the 0 properly.

Comment: I prefer to check if `$str` is a actually string as well.

Comment: @Pallazzo Yea you definitely have to make sure it's a string. I figured that's what Sean meant.

Comment: strlen() behaved stupid until 5.3 if fed an array as argument. You would get length 5 because array typecasts to the string 'Array'. So this isn't an ideal way to kill 2 birds with one stone; you still need to verify it was a string.

Comment: Yes I understand you may want to test for a string, but thats pretty straightforward. Whereas using !== can often break things

Comment: @Sean H Jenkins I see how `!=` might break things but `!==` seems fine. What do you mean?

Comment: For example if you have (int) 5 === (float) 5 = false But (int)5 == (float) 5 = true